# Go to an URL without actually doing so

Tags: php, html, get

I have a http `GET` method url;

```
http://test.com/test.php?name=sam&age=20
```

Now I'm in a different website and I want to call, or say ping that URL so that the 'get' content is pushed without actually begin redirected into that URL.

Is there a function or method in php to get it done?

Comment: Why use `GET` if you don't want to get anything?

Comment: do you mean to fetch data from this url `http://test.com/test.php?name=sam&age=20` to another url?

Comment: Are you talking about something like [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) where a request is made in the background?

Comment: @gpgekko it's a predefined url which i have to pass data without actually visiting the test site [get URl]

Comment: may be you can use curl

Comment: @freefaller something like that, i don't know AJAX well, just need to pass the data

Comment: @CodingAnt raises a good question - are you talking about this ping being initiated on the client browser via `javascript`, or on the server in `php`?

Comment: @CodingAnt in the server , php

Comment: @gpgekko - `POST` and `GET` have nothing to do with the direction, they are the method with which the `<form>` transmits information *from* the browser.

Comment: @Isuru - in that case CodingAnt has the answer, look at [CURL](https://php.net/curl)

Comment: Please tell us more about what `test.php` actually does, **why** you want to GET it, and what you want to happen to the data you GET from it.

Comment: @freefaller No, `POST` and `GET` are HTTP methods. They apply to any kind of calls. And yeah, you can use any method to call the url, but if you ask for content, you shouldn't be surprised to actually get the content you asked for...

Comment: @gpgekko kinda hard to explain my problem, first of all, isnt the above test domain url callde an http get url?  AND i want to like ping the above URL with the above url so that data is passed, without me moving from my current domain

Comment: @gpgekko - and that is exactly what the OP is asking for - how to call the URL without actually navigating to it. That is where AJAX for client-side and CURL for server-side come into it.

Comment: @Wooble I'm in mysite.com, which i develop, and there is test.com which is a site controlled by someone else. No I want to send the data in the above url. in the conventional method, i will have to visit the 'http://test.com/test.php?name=sam&age=20' to pass that data, which losses my control over the person using my site. Can I like ping the site without the user leaving my site

Comment: *"i don't know AJAX well, just need to pass the data"* ... if this is for giving data to the server, then it is important to realise that a GET request is the wrong thing to use; it should be a POST request. Why is this important? Other than semantics, also because search engines will follow GET URLs when they crawl a site; if you don't want them doing that, use a POST request instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cURL reference](https://php.net/curl)

Eg,

```
    $urlStringData = "http://test.com/test.php?name=sam&age=20";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); # timeout after 10 seconds, you can increase it
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlStringData ); #set the url and get string together

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```